# Blender Game - music problem

Tags: game-engine

I have a problem with soundtrack and sounds
In the Blender Game (while using blender) sounds and music seems right and i can clearly hear both of them. but when i export my game as game engine runtime, and then play my game, sounds and music disappears. Can somebody help me?

Comment: Did you packed your sounds inside the blend file? Try using external sound files, relative to the blend file.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to fix this problem is to pack the sounds inside your blend file..

Use the menu command : File -> External Data -> Pack All into .blend file.

[image]

(It also gives you some fps boost!)